# how to convert utf8 to iso-8859-7?

Tags: android, c, utf-8

I have legacy C code that does text processing. All rules and data are encoded in ISO-8859-7. Now, I am trying to port to android. I have build the appropriate `JNI` function that `GetStringUTFChars()`. This const char* seems to be `UTF-8`. So, I need to convert to ISO.

In Windows, I have a function that converts `utf-8 (const char*)` to `wchar_t` and then I use `wcstombs()` to convert to ISO. But, this does not work under Android, I also read that wchar_t is not safe.

So, how can I perform this conversion?

Thank you

Comment: Why would `wcstombs` not work?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ISO-8859-7 is a multi-byte string but `wcstombs` looks like it expects a wide string.

Comment: Look up if `iconv` library is available on Android

Comment: @simonc My point is that `wcstombs` is the same everywhere. Perhaps the issue is that the utf8 -> utf16 part isn't available on Android. But I think I'd want to use a conversion library that did the conversion in a single step. So, iconv would be a good choice.

Comment: iconv seems too-much complicated to (compile and) use in my app. The easiest solution was to implement a lookup table. Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

To get from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-7.
First convert from UTF-8 to native unicode and then from native unicode to ISO-8859-7. However, UTF-8 potentially allows over 60000 code points from almost all modern scripts while ISO-8859-7 allows only 256. Therefore, you should be aware of data loss and try to keep your data in unicode/UTF-8, if possible.

As of now, you can use any android specific API if available(I am aware of a iconv-android API) or the GNU C `libiconv` library for your conversions.